# Fetch invoices by user id in Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I want to fetch all invoices a user has raised using the Eloquent ORM.

At the moment, I'm fetching the `invoice.id` from a join table UsersInvoices by the `user.id` and then looping through and fetching the invoices from the Invoices table based on the id.

```
$user = Sentry::getUser();
$invoiceIDs = UsersInvoice::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get()->toArray();
$invoices = array();

foreach ($invoiceIDs as $key => $row) {
    array_push($invoices, Invoice::find($row['invoice_id']));
}



$this->data['title'] = 'Invoices';
$this->data['invoices'] = $invoices;


/** render the template */
App::render('@invoices/pending/index.twig', $this->data);
```

But I think this could/should be handled by the ORM by modelling the relationship between user and invoices.

It looks as though I should be able to manage this [like so](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many) by simply posting the `user.id` into the invoices table as a foreign key - Maybe I don't need a join table as there is nothing that is unique to the relationship that needs to be stored... ?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use different approach instead of running query for each invoice. You can use  relationships (probably without pivot table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Posting from my phone. Sorry, I can't put code examples that way.

If I understand correctly, the relationships between Users and Invoices are

```
- User hasMany Invoice

- Invoice belongsTo User
```

If so then you'll need to set it up in the Eloquent models by defining the relationship and methods to get at the relayed data (at least in the User model). The Eloquent ORM expects there to be a user_id field in the invoices table.

Then you can do:

```
$user = User::find($id);

$user->invoices(); //assuming you put an invoices method in the User model
```

Or:

```
$invoice = Invoice::find($id);

$invoice->user(); //assuming you setup a user method in the Invoice model
```

More info on relationships here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

Comment: Your examples `User::relation()` are wrong - you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks, Jarek! I corrected the pseudo code to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have stored the `user_id` and `invoice_id` in a separate table.
Simply keep `user_id` in the `Invoices` table and then use a single query to fetch all.
And also do not convert the results to array.

```
foreach( $invoices as $inv ) {
    echo $inv->invoice_id;
}
```